# Complex Pivoting in Pandas involving multiple columns

Tags: pandas

My df:

```
t           name    team    Value
1-Jan-10    Roger   Ajou    10
1-Jan-10    Kim      KSR    20
1-Jan-10    Tim      KKR    0
2-Jan-10    Tim      KKR    10
2-Jan-10    Roger    Ajou   20
3-Jan-10    Kim      KSR    20
3-Jan-10    Tim      KKR    10
3-Jan-10    Roger    Ajou   0
```

I tried pandas pivoting but, here I need to pivot 2 column together and expected output is like below

```
            KSR     Ajou    KKR
            Kim     Roger   Tim
1-Jan-10    20       10       0
2-Jan-10             20      10
3-Jan-10    20        0      10
```

Note: the column are sorted based on 'name' column. Is this doable in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape, then sorting by second level in `MultiIndex` and last remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['t','team','name'])['Value']
         .unstack([1,2], fill_value=0)
         .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=[None, None]))
print (df1)
         KSR  Ajou KKR
         Kim Roger Tim
1-Jan-10  20    10   0
2-Jan-10   0    20  10
3-Jan-10  20     0  10
```

Comment: Thanks! Can we merge on MultiIndex as well?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit pain. For select use insted `df['column']` tuples like `df[('KSR','Kim')]`